# Javascript access and write object sub-value through array of successive keys

Tags: javascript

How can I get the method `getValueThroughPath(object, keysArray)` that works like so:

```
var object = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {
        key4: "value"
      }  
    }
  }
}

getValueThroughPath(object, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']); // = "value" and undefined if wrong path
```

?

I'm also looking for the `setValueThroughPath(object, keysArray)` equivalent method.

*I use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) if this can shorten the solution*.

Comment: Use the bracket notation

Comment: How about `_.get(object, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will walk the object down to the last key.  If any key is misspelled or missing, it will return `undefined`:

```js
function getValueThroughPath(obj, keys) {
  while(obj=obj[keys.shift()] || '', keys.length);
  return obj || undefined;
}

function setValueThroughPath(obj, keys, val) {
  while(keys.length>1) {
    obj[keys[0]]= obj[keys[0]] || {};
    obj= obj[keys.shift()];
  };
  obj[keys[0]]= val;
}

var object = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {
        key4: "value"
      }  
    }
  }
}

setValueThroughPath(object, ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'], 'Eureka!');
setValueThroughPath(object, ['this', 'is', 'a', 'new', 'test'], 'Hallelujah!');

console.log(getValueThroughPath(object, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']));   // "value"
console.log(getValueThroughPath(object, ['key1', 'key2', 'key5', 'key4']));   // undefined
console.log(getValueThroughPath(object, ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']));        // "Eureka!"
console.log(getValueThroughPath(object, ['this', 'is', 'a', 'new', 'test'])); // "Hallelujah!"
```

Comment: This is even more elegant solution than the duplicate-one answers. :)

Comment: Thanks, just noticed your `setValueThroughPath` request.  Now added.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your object properties and get the appropriate value using a function like this:

```
function getValueThroughPath(object, keys) {
    var temp = object;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp = temp[key];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
        } else {
            console.log('Couldnt find key ' + key);
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

You can check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/bx82akj5/ to see it working (open console to check it out! =D)

I used the "hasOwnProperty" method so you don't end up accessing an inexistent property or accessing a property of Object in javascript, so you iterate only through the properties defined in your object.

The function setValueTrhoughPath that you are looking for is pretty much the same (just analogous, of course)